# How to store data inside an iOS-based CMS app?

Tags: ios, database, react-native, asyncstorage

I want to develop an app, which will store information (text) locally on the phone.

I'm new to iOS development and wanted to find out if there's any internal DB system that is recommended to use to store data or if there's some other solution like AsyncStorage used in conjunction with React Native...

Sorry if the question is a bit general, but I could not make it more specific due to the lack of information I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Realm for React Native](https://realm.io/communities/react-native/) to store data.
It's easy to start ORM database which can be used on Android/iOS.